# RSQLite using group-by for functions within the query

Tags: sql, r, sqlite, group-by

I am very new to SQL (using it in R currently with RSQLite and DBI packages)

I am trying to create a column that is the absolute mean deviation, aka:

(i) - AVG(i,g)

Where i is the individual occurence and the AVG component is the average for the group. What I am having troubles with is making sure the AVG component is the only part that gets grouped. When I do GROUP BY, it groups everything and doesn't give me the right number.

Here is the sample data:

| student | class | grade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | English | 79 |
| A | Spanish | 65 |
| A | Chemistry | 92 |
| B | English | 46 |
| B | Spanish | 83 |
| B | Chemistry | 78 |
| C | English | 67 |
| C | Spanish | 87 |
| C | Chemistry | 98 |
| D | English | 99 |
| D | Spanish | 80 |
| D | Chemistry | 75 |

Basically I would want the individual GRADE for a student in a class to compare with the average of that student (e.g. the individual english grade - the total average for a student)

Iha ve tried the following:

```
dbGetQuery(gradesdb, "SELECT student, 
                      ABS(grade-AVG(grade)) AS mad
                      FROM grades
                      GROUP BY student,class")
```

This gives me 0 for all of the stat values (which I gather is because the group by is going on all selected operations within the query)

how can I make it so that the AVG portion of the calculation is only "grouped" by the student.
I get the right calculation if I do:

```
dbGetQuery(gradesdb2, "SELECT student, 
                      ABS(grade-AVG(grade)) AS mad
                      FROM grades
                      GROUP BY student")
```

But then I only get the first class for each student, instead of the stat for each class with the student average.

I want to do this all in SQL and not calculate the average as a seperate column with base R or tidyverse.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Are you trying to get the MAD per class, or the MAD per student, or something else?

Comment: MAD per student, so the student A outcome would be:  0.4,13.6,13.4 for each class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider turning `AVG()` via `GROUPBY` to `AVG()` via a [window function](https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html):

```sql
SELECT student, 
       ABS(grade - AVG(grade) OVER (PARTITION BY student)) AS mad
FROM grades
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much!